# How to combine multiple ADSL lines?

Tags: switch, vlan, load-balancing, adsl

Before beginning, I'm totally new to advanced network topics and not working as a professional network engineer or so. Just trying to learn some stuff.

My problem is, I have 3 different ADSL (or VDSL) lines at my office and want to combine them to;

1. Increase the throughput
2. Load-balancing
3. Increase the connection uptime
4. Have better management over WAN-LAN connections

To achive this I'm planning to create a network structure as in the following diagram.
[image]

So my questions are;

1. What is the name of the topology/design that I'm trying to create?
2. Is it possible/feasible to combine multiple DSL lines?
3. If so, what is the device that I need to put inside of big red circle?

Additional information;

- I need at least 40 ports to connect all of the devices
- VLAN management is required to separate the networks
- Gigabit connection is required to use inside the local network operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a router with multiple WAN ports and load-balancing capability (most business-grade routers will do) and a managed switch for connecting the clients.

The load balancing can distribute traffic to/from multiple WAN links and provide fail over. However, any one connection can only use one of the WAN links at a time.

Depending on the router model, you can set load distribution based on utilization, source address (group/subnet), protocol, ...

If you want more control over the Internet connections you need a decent firewall. There's an extreme wide range of features and capabilities, so you'd need to add your requirements to your question.

A managed switch connects the clients to the router and allows you to set up separate subnets using VLANs. Most likely you'd want to connect each VLAN to the router, so you need to set up a VLAN trunk between the router and the switch.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Do you have any brand&model suggestions for  MultiWAN port routers? And is it ok to use TP-link T2600G-18TS as a managed switch for VLAN management?

Comment: Sorry, product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. You could try on [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).